# Can't find PHP interpreter in PHPStorm

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, phpstorm

I am on Mac OS, and installed PHP5.4, php54-mcrypt, and php54-xdebug using Homebrew. The PHPStorm version is 7.1.3. The executable are located in /usr/local/bin, which are listed as so

```
angelas-mbp:bin angelawang$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
angelas-mbp:bin angelawang$ ls -l | grep php
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        31 Sep  3 11:03 pear -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/pear
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        34 Sep  3 11:03 peardev -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/peardev
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        31 Sep  3 11:03 pecl -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/pecl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        31 Sep  3 11:03 phar -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/phar
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        36 Sep  3 11:03 phar.phar -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/phar.phar
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        30 Sep  3 11:03 php -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/php
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        34 Sep  3 11:03 php-cgi -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/php-cgi
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        37 Sep  3 11:03 php-config -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/php-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 angelawang  admin        33 Sep  3 11:03 phpize -> ../Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin/phpize
```

However, when entering '/usr/local/bin' or '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.27/bin', PHPStorm can not find the PHP interpreter.

Comment: If you use `/usr/local/bin/php --version`, does it give the expected output?

Comment: @Smar yes it does, along with XDebug version.

Comment: Please try PhpStorm **v8 EAP** build -- AFAIK it has few fixes/improvements in this area: http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm . As for v7.1.3 -- try disabling all extensions (temporarily) and see if it will help (sometimes does) -- it's only needed for PhpStorm to confirm PHP version etc -- once done it should work OK with extra extensions enabled back.

Comment: @LazyOne I disabled all plugin except PHP, and still no dice :(

Comment: Have you tried v8 yet? If it behaves the same -- then I may only suggest submitting a ticket to their Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Make sure that `php --version` gives you version at the first output string. Sometimes it reports issues with your missing lib's (as it was in my case) before printing the version string. Thus phpStorm couldn't guess php's version.

Comment: I had a similar issue to @Blindfold, except my error was the xdebug was being loaded twice (since it's seems to be compiled into php directly in yosemite).  Once that was fixed PHPStorm was happy.